# How to get updated innerHTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag, innerhtml

I have this page contains 3 draggable divs.

I'm using JQuery to drag these divs on the page.

Now when I drag them to different positions.

their attributes values should be changed to the new positions.

for example when the page loads the first div value:

```
<div style='position:absolute;left:1px;top:1px;'>
```

after I drag the box it should be changed to new position. the  should show updated innerHTML but it seems not to be working.

and no I dont wanna use the findposition function because this is only a sample and I have wide range of attributes/objects.

so what I need is to get the updated innerHTML of .
is there any way to do this with javascript?

thanks

Comment: When does innerHTML change? Also you should post some code that you've written so far.

Comment: nevermind, I just found the solution.

Comment: I was using different method.
I just used this code and it seems to be outputting the updated HTML.
response = document.body.innerHTML;

Answer (score 1):

I was using `$.get('page.html', function(response){});`.

I just changed it to:

```
response = document.body.innerHTML;
```

Now everything is workin like charm.

Comment: In case you're interested, previously you were downloading the original page from the server, which is why it was unaffected by your scripted updates.